# How does Nginx 1.21.0 use variables in ssl_certificate?

Tags: variables, nginx, path

Example URL:[ssvwv.com](http://ssvwv.com/)
`set $a ssvwv.com;`
`ssl_certificate /www/$a/fn.pem;`

I see in the error log that the path becomes:`/www//fn.pem`

Correct should be:`/www/ssvwv.com/fn.pem`
Nginx 1.21.0 version variable is invalid?
[Since version 1.15.9 Variables can be used](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate)
Using the `$ssl_server_name.crt` variable to the file name is invalid.
example:`/www/ssvwv.com/$a.pem`
error result:`/www/ssvwv.com/.pem`

variable example:`$ssl_server_name` Variable value:`www.ssvwv.com`
path example:`/www/ssvwv.com/$ssl_server_name.pem`
error result:`/www/ssvwv.com/.pem`
The test is invalid in the path variable.

Answer (score 0):

**ssl_certificate** is set inside your blockserver

See an example below

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your_private.key;
    root /path/to/webroot;
    server_name your_domain.com;
}
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
    location / {
        root /var/www/;
        root  /home/www/public_html/your.domain.com/public/;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: You must set the full path of the file

Comment: How could the path be variable? does not make sense

Comment: It makes sense for multiple paths.